# Screen goes white when posting a comment

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app, ios

Since iOS 11.2 all the way through 12.2 beta 4, if you post or discard a comment on any post on any SE community, the screen will turn white. This has been ongoing continuously **for a year now**, and it affects both the SE app and the SO app.

You can go back to the previous screen and open the question again, and everything appears as normal. You can also rotate the screen to get the text to come back. Using the arrows to navigate between the question and answers updates the HUD, but the screen remains white unless one of the above is done to get the text back.

> [image: white screen after posting a comment]

UPDATE:
After posting **anything** (comment, answer), the screen goes all white except for the sidebar. Perhaps it is intentional, but I prefer last week’s behavior of going back to the content. Not major, since the sidebar icons still work.

Comment: same issue reported for SO App [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359318/white-screen-after-edit-post-comment-in-ios-so-se-app)

Comment: @SurajRao If that’s also reporting for SE, should these threads be merged?

Comment: @DonielF that's not possible, because that issue is reported on another site.

Comment: @Glorfindel Ah. Missed that. Just saw “Meta Stack” and assumed the last word was “Exchange.” :)

Comment: This also happens if you discard a comment instead of posting it.

Comment: @Tim Really no point in putting up a bounty. Development work on the mobile apps is on hiatus.

Comment: @Ano Then they should take the time to roll back 1 version. I'm gonna kick up a stink about this because the app is my main interface. This bug is unacceptable.

Comment: @Tim this is the rare case when Android app is better than for an iOS. Consider the changing you mobile platform :) My apologies for mockery in advance.

Comment: I've hit this a few times recently.

Comment: @Jeremy maybe you can have some influence, favors to redeem, etc? All it takes is few moments of Brian's time (I bet he already fixed this bug on his dev environment), and the critical part is management authorization to push the fix.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm doubtful it would make a difference, so I'm afraid I'm selfishly saving whatever influence I have for issues that personally effect me more than this. =P

Comment: This also occurs on the iPad.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog does stopping development mean stopping buxfixes too? Is the app status detailed on meta somewhere you can link?

Comment: @DoritoStyle Apparently, since I posted this a year ago with no improvement since then.

Comment: @DoritoStyle Yep. No new updates except to fix absolutely critical bugs (app stops working entirely, major security flaw, etc.)

Comment: @Sonic I don't think they'll bother fixing even a major security flaw. They'll much more likely just shut down the app for good.

Comment: is the Android app still in active development? is it just the iOS app not being developed?