# Why am I getting a blank page on mobile after adding a comment?

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app

*I encountered this situation a few times before, but I didn't care much. This is a bit annoying for mobile users, me alike.*

Yesterday I added a comment to [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/91390/19902) using the Stack Exchange iOS mobile app, which was for my own question. After that, I was greeted with a blank page, which you can see below. Commenting was successful, and it's there. Why is this happening?

EDIT: I was made aware that this question already has an answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302840/266370), but it doesn't. The OP probably put their comment as an answer.

[image: Blank page].

I am running version 1.6.6.2 of the app.

Comment: The answer on my question, apparently, is that SE doesn’t care about the quality of its iOS app, as this has been ongoing for over **sixteen months**. The fact that there are no proper answers yet doesn’t mean that this isn’t an exact duplicate.